# aiohttp throws Session is closed error without visible reasons

Tags: python, parsing, aiohttp

Im trying to fetch a batch of urls in different ways:

via simple loop like:
`for url in url_list: await Parser.fetch(url)`

or via gather:
`await asyncio.gather(*(Parser.fetch(url) for url in url_list))`

Aiohttp sessions was created and closed in context managers of Parser:

```
async def __aenter__(self):
    session_list = []
    for index, proxy_str in enumerate(self._ru_proxy_list):
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=ProxyConnector(host=host, port=port, username=login,
                                                                 password=password, enable_cleanup_closed=True), 
                                        timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=20))
        session_list.append(session)
    self._session_list = session_list
    self.session_pool = cycle(self._session_list)
    return self

async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    for session in self._session_list:
        await session.close()
```

The multipurpose url fech_func looks like this:

```
async def get_via_aiohttp(self, url, request_info: Union[str, dict], request_method='get', json_decode=False)
    session = next(self.session_pool)

    # New thing to check session state, since this problem is occured
    if session_dict['aiohttp'].closed:
        self._session_list[index] = await self._open_proxy_connection(self._ru_proxy_list[index], index)

    try:
        async with getattr(session, request_method)(url, **request_info) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                return await response.json() if json_decode else await response.read()
            else:
                raise ValueError(response.status, url)
    except (asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError, ProxyTimeoutError, ProxyError, ServerDisconnectedError,
            ClientOSError, RuntimeError, ConnectionResetError, OSError) as err:
        # Yes, I sometimes get ALL of this exceptions, but the RuntimeError the most annoying
        logging.error(f'Error was cought.\n{err}')
        # Here close manually and open the session like i do it __aenter__, then replace it. I also know the position of session in self._session_list via index (it isnt presented in code).
        return await self.get_via_aiohttp(url, request_info, json_decode=json_decode,
                                          request_method=request_method)
```

Sometimes i get Runtime error: session is closed. No matter how i try to parse concurrently via gather or one by one... Why?

To clarify the main function is:

```
async def main():
    async with Parser(config):
        ...  # Here all parsing stuff with scheduler
        while True:
            try:
                 await asyncio.sleep(3600)
            except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt, CancelledError):
                break
```

So sessions cant be closed theirselfs, but it happens :/

PS. Python 3.9.12, aiohttp 3.8.3

Session shouldnt be closed by theirselfs. There are no error should be occured at least in case of sequential parsing...

Comment: So, i think the main problem hiding in asyncio behavior... I'll try to test my parser without any asyncio.gather() (etc) with only step by step parsing, like url after url.